# Implement Pagination On frequently changing Table Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In My Database, Table ***ChatMessage*** Which have column
**Identifier, Message, Sender, Receiver**.

Now In my Repository, I have method to Get Messages.

```
public IQueryable<ChatMessage> GetChatMessage(int PageNo, int PageSize, int ownerUserId, int friendUserId)
{
    var query = this.GetQueryable().
        Where(x => (x.Sender.Identifier == ownerUserId && x.Receiver.Identifier == friendUserId) ||
                    (x.Sender.Identifier == friendUserId && x.Receiver.Identifier == ownerUserId));
    query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier).Skip((PageNo - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
    return query;
}
```

It is working fine. But there is a scenario: let I open the page, get the first 10 records, at the same time OtherUser send me 2 more messages.

Now when I'll click on second page then I'll get next 10 messages, but it will include 2 duplicate message(Which I have already got on first page.)

How to avoid this ?

I want when I click on second page, then I want to retrieve next 10 records, excluding counting those 2 new messages.

Note: I don't want to store last retrieve row number in session, as this is chat system and there may be many users chatting simultaneously.

I want to do this because see this is the case.

default I loaded only last 10 messages.
[image]

Now On clicking **loadmore**, I'll prepend next 10 messages to old `li`

see 
[image]

Comment: Because I'm showing all the chat message on same page by prepend the next messages on same `li`. Just like fb , on retrieving the old message It just prepend old message to messagebox.

Comment: Why downvote. Please explain

Comment: Get the ID of the oldest message of the previous page. Then before appending the current page, filter and append the messages which have ids older than that id

Comment: or If you want exact 10 messages in the next page, you could pass the time of the oldest message in the previous page as a parameter and select 10 messages which are older than that time in your repository.

Comment: You say "I don't want to store last retrieve row number in session, as this is chat system and there may be many users chatting simultaneously." That doesn't make sense to me. First of all, you can and probably should store that on the client, not the server. Secondly, if there are many users chatting simultaneously, there will be many messages sent by each of those users. How will remembering one id per session suddenly kill the scalability?

Comment: That's why all common messaging systems have continuous scrolling in stead of paging.

Comment: @GertArnold: Scrolling will also do the same . It will fetch next 10 records, which I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, but you can de-duplicate client-side. But you may also want to implement a push mechanism (for example, SignalR, which is really not that hard).

Comment: @GertArnold: I'm using signalR for Push messages. but loading messages doesn't related to SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the client when you're sending all those parameters, pass the **time of the oldest message** (Page number is not required). Then in your repository

```
public IQueryable<ChatMessage> GetChatMessage(int pageSize, int ownerUserId, int friendUserId, DateTime oldestMessageDate)
{
   var query = this.GetQueryable().
              Where(x => ((x.Sender.Identifier == ownerUserId && x.Receiver.Identifier == friendUserId) 
                     || (x.Sender.Identifier == friendUserId && x.Receiver.Identifier == ownerUserId)) 
                     && x.MessageTime < oldestMessageDate); 
    //query now has all the messages older than messages shown to the user

    query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier).Take(PageSize);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Where should I store this datetime variable for different users.  also see my comment on another answer.

Comment: Is this implemented using ChatJs?

Comment: No . It is just a span tag (load more), I wrote click event on that span to load previous records.

Comment: Create an array clientside with UserId and DateTime property and save it in SessionStorage/LocalStorage. Everytime you get the Array of ChatMessages, add/update the oldest datetime against the UserId.

Comment: Ok . Which would be better Cookies or browser LocalStorage.

Comment: You need the array for client side purposes only. So use LocalStorage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99468/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-adiga).